# How setuidgid command works

Tags: centos6

I have seen in one of script used setuidgid and i am not able to understand how this is working. Also tried to find on google but did not get much. Any help would be much appreciated.

commands:

```
/usr/bin/setuidgid -G commonconfig -G commonlog -G lock scriptconfig /usr/local/bin/scriptconfig
```

Answer (score 4):

`Daemontools` is the collection of tools for managing `UNIX` services.
**Running Service With a Specific User:**
Create a sample service for clear understanding:

```
mkdir /services/yourservice  
vim /services/yourservice/run.sh
```

In that run.sh. add the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec setuidgid <user_name> <command>
```

Save it and change the permissions by using this command:

```
chmod 755 run.sh
```

Then link with your services:

```
ln -s /services/yourservice/ /service/
```

This should create a service which is associates with a specified user.
**setuidgid cmd can also be used for logging:**
Create an user:

```
adduser <user_name>
```

then create the folders like this:

```
mkdir /services/somerandomservice/log
mkdir /services/somerandomservice/log/main
```

Then assign `main` folder with the new user that you created:

```
chown <user_name> /services/somerandomservice/log/main
```

Create a file:

```
vim /services/somerandomservice/log/run.sh
```

Add the following in that file:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec setuidgid <user_name> multilog t ./main
```

Save it, change file permissions:

```
chmod 755 run.sh
```

Now, all logs regarding the user which you created should go to `/main/` folder.
I hope that you understood it now.

Comment: Thanks Ajay, really helped. :)

Comment: Thank you, This post saved me a lot of hours of effort.